# Finding a distinct set of fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following JSON collection in MongoDB.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57529381551673386c9150a6"),
    "team_code": 3,
    "team_id": 2
},
{
     "_id": ObjectId("57529381551673386c91514a"),
     "team_code": 4,
     "team_id": 5
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("57529381551673386c91514b"),
   "team_code": 3,
   "team_id": 2
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("57529381551673386c91514c"),
   "team_code": 4,
   "team_id": 5,
}
```

As it can be seen from the data , there a 2 records each with (`team_code=3, team_id =2`) and  (`team_code =4, team_id=5`).
Is it possible to get the distinct set of team codes and team ids.
Some thing like ,

```
{
 "team_code" : 3, "team_id" : 2
},
{
 "team_code" : 4, "team_id" : 5,
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using the following *Aggregation Pipeline*:

```
var distinctIdCode = { $group: { _id: { team_code: "$team_code", team_id: "$team_id" } } }
db.foo.aggregate([distinctIdCode])
```

This will give you:

```
{ "_id" : { "team_code" : 4, "team_id" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_code" : 3, "team_id" : 2 } }
```

This query returns new documents created from the documents in your collection.  The documents returned have an `_id` which is the result of grouping the collection documents on the `team_code` and `team_id` fields.

Comment: Why `Aggregation Pipeline`? This can be achieved using `find` itself. See [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections)

Comment: use aggregate because the results are to be grouped based on unique (distinct) combinations of team_code and team_id.  This is one of the things the aggregation pipeline is designed to do well.

Comment: @robjwilkins thanks rob. I was wondering if i put this in a variable, say var temp , how do i access the fields ..?

Answer (score 0):

For Java code:

```
    Bson field1 = new Document("team_code", "$team_code").append("team_id", "$team_id");Bson groupField = new Document("_id", field1 );
    Bson group = new Document("$group", groupField );List<Bson> bsonList = new ArrayList<Bson>(); 
    bsonList.add(group);    
    com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable<Document> res=collection.aggregate( bsonList );
      for (Document doc : res) {
         Document subDoc=(Document)doc.get("_id");
         System.out.println(subDoc.get("team_code")+" : "+subDoc.get("team_id"));
        //deptEnvs.put(subDoc.getInteger("dept"), subDoc.getString("smEnv"));  

         }
```